# GA4 events only show up in realtime after 48 hours

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am attempting to create GA4 analytics events by POST-ing to the URL with the same details as a web app:

```
curl -X POST "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=2&tid=<MY_TID>&cid=<MY_CID>&t=event&en=someNonsense&ep.aParameter=value&z=1234567890" -H "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" -H "sec-fetch-mode: no-cors" -H "sec-fetch-site: cross-site" -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty" -H "pragma: no-cache" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "origin: http://localhost:5000" -H "content-length: 0" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "user-agent: dummy"
```

All of these events show up perfectly in the realtime view, and if I add `&_dbg=1` to the URL, these events and all their parameters show up consistently and reliably in the DebugView too.

I waited 48 hours and the events didn't show up. I did the following to try to bring things to life:

- added all the event parameters as custom metrics
- disabled the internal traffic filter which is active by default
- dug through the settings and agreed to the "Data Processing Terms"

I then waited a further 48 hours and nothing has changed. Things seem to work just fine if I do them through a browser with firebase-analytics.js.

Does anyone have any idea what I've missed/broken?

Is Google doing some post processing on events to make sure they're coming from a real web page? I can mimic the HTTPS requests of the browser and the events still wont get recorded.

Comment: I've read that bot filtering could be a likely culprit, but it seems that I can't disable it for GA4?

Comment: This is usual issue with GA4. It is still buggy. I recommend you to setup BigQuery export (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en). From my findings, if you can see the event in BigQuery event, then you just need to wait several days to show up in GA4 interface. They will show up. DebugView and RealTime report are not reliable. BigQuery is source that you can rely on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get things working.

It turns out GA4 will not log events unless they are part of a session. If I send a `session_start` event with `ga_session_number` and `ga_session_id` properties, any subsequent events will be properly recorded for the duration of the session.

Answer (score 0):

I can see my events showing up in realtime on my GA4 account.  Perhaps you need to debug your events using the https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder/